# Why does abstract override fail

Tags: scala, akka, mixins

I discovered that using abstract types affects the scala compiler ability to detect overrides and it interprets seemingly correct code as erroneous.

```
trait I {
  type T
  def doThings(t : T) : Unit
}
type IT[X] = I { type T = X}

trait A extends I {
  override type T = AnyRef
  def doThings(t : T) : Unit = println("A")
}

trait Z[X] extends I { this : IT[X] =>
  abstract override def doThings(t : T) : Unit = {
    println("Z")
    super.doThings(t)
  }
}

object Use {
  val az = new A with Z[AnyRef] {}
}
```

The scala compiler fires such error:

```
OverloadAbstract.scala:44: error: object creation impossible, since method doThings in trait Z of type (t: this.T)Unit is marked `abstract' and `override', but no concrete implementation could be found in a base class
    val az = new A with Z[AnyRef] {}
```

*What is the proper way to express such relations between trait mixing and implementation?*

---

For the comparison that code works fine:

```
trait I {
  def doThings() : Unit
}

class A extends I {
  def doThings() : Unit = println("A")
}

trait Z extends I {
  abstract override def doThings() : Unit = {
    println("Z")
    super.doThings()
  }
}

object Use {
  val az = new A with Z {}
}
```

---

The real use case is to implement a forwarder for the `akka.event.EventBus`:

```
object PartialEventBus {
  type ApplyEvent[E] = EventBus { type Event = E }
}

trait ForwardEventBus[E] extends EventBus { this : PartialEventBus.ApplyEvent[E] =>
  def relay : PartialEventBus.ApplyEvent[E]

  abstract override def publish(event : Event) : Unit = {
    relay.publish(event)
    super.publish(event)
  }
}
```

Type parametrization for the `ForwardEventBus` is needed for compiler to match object-wide `this.Event` type with external `relay.Event` type. Compiler would fail without such hint because of scala's path-dependent types restrictions.

Comment: It's losing `T`, since self-type `self: A =>` works. Maybe someone can say why. Tricky to get bounds on abstract type members to work with self-types, but I don't see the reason here offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm confused, shouldn't the question be "Why does abstract override succeed?"  Section 5.2.4 of the spec covers `abstract override`, and it says, "The override modifier has an additional significance when combined with the abstract modifier. That modifier combination is only allowed for value members of traits."

I hope a language lawyer can weigh in, but it looks like this should not be legal.

Comment: very strange, abstract override methods are used widely: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html